# VBA - reference 1 cell from 40 XL files into 40 rows

Tags: vba, excel

**Code is not doing as expected (read further below for details)**

1. It's not reading the contents of cells A1 thru A36, but just returning "A36".
2. It returns A36 for all records B1 thru B36.  So the loop is messed up.  I expected A1 for B1, A10 for B10, etc.

**Summary**

I'm summing the dollar amounts for 3 years, using 36 XL files (naming convention and file-path are the same except for the month used).  My destination XL is cells **B1 to B36**, one cell per month, source XL uses worksheet Sum_Total cell **A4** (same for all 36 XL files)

**Naming and file-path convention:**

```
T:\folder1\folder2\2010\201001\201001.xls  
T:\folder1\folder2\2011\201105\201105.xls  
T:\folder1\folder2\2012\201212\201212.xls
```

**Ideally, I want cells B1 thru B36 to have this formula:**

```
='T:\folder1\folder2\2010\201001\[201001.xls]Sum_plan'!$A$4   
='T:\folder1\folder2\2011\201101\[201101.xls]Sum_plan'!$A$4
```

**Cells A1 thru A36 will be named this:**

```
A1 = 201001  
A4 = 201004  
A36 = 201212
```

**Heres the code I have thus far.  The macro runs successfully, but doesn't give what I want.**

```
Sub sum()
Dim ThisMonth As Integer 'will be A3 thru A36 to show 201001,201002,...
Dim SlidingRange As Integer 'B3 thru B36 to show destination location
For ThisMonth = 1 To 36
    For SlidingRange = 1 To 36
        Range("B" & SlidingRange).Formula = "'T:\folder1\folder2\" & Left("A" & ThisMonth, 4) & "\" & "A" & ThisMonth\["&ThisMonth&".xls]Sum_Total'!$A$4"
    Next SlidingRange
Next ThisMonth
End Sub
```

**What the code actually gives me...**

Repeated on every line from B1 thru B36 is this

```
'T:\folder1\folder2\A36\A36\[A36.xls]Sum_total'!$A$4
```

Comment: You are looping 36x36 times, each 36 times overwriting `B1:B36`. Naturally you get the result of the last overwrite in the end.

Comment: Remove the SlidingRange loop and use `Range("B" & ThisMonth).Formula = ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are qualifying the ranges with the wrong syntax and you have two loops.

Update to this:

```
For ThisMonth = 1 To 36

    Dim sYear as String, sMonth as String
    sYear = Left(Range("A" & ThisMonth).Value,4)
    sMonth = Range("A" & ThisMonth).Value

    Range("B" & ThisMonth).Formula = "'T:\folder1\folder2\" & sYear & "\" & sMonth & "\[" & sMonth & ".xls]Sum_Total'!$A$4"

Next ThisMonth
```

Comment: you missed the `)` in `Range("B" & ThisMonth).Formula`, plus, according to OP, the pattern should be `"'T:\folder1\folder2\" & sYear & "\" & sYear & sMonth & "\[" & sYear & sMonth & ".xls] ...`

Comment: Genuine question: why does `sMonth` contains 4 characters? Shouldn't it be `Right(Range("A" & ThisMonth).Value,2)` instead, while `sYear` is `Left(Range("A" & ThisMonth).Value,4)`?

Comment: Thanks @VictorMoraes - I think my eyes were playing tricks on me and I wrapped the left around the wrong variable.

Comment: Also, Next thismonth not Next this month. Or just leave it out?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman The code you provided works perfectly.  Thank you.  
At) VictorMoraes - thanks for the info, work, and for looking over the post.  In case this hasn't been resolved, the left(xxxx,4) thing was just to grab the "2010" from "201001" for a folder directory.